# How do I keep an iOS 5 Tweet sheet from canceling if I switch apps?

Tags: ios, twitter

I am writing an app that involves sending emails, tweets, and Facebook messages (in that order) from a user's phone. The problem is that if the user multitasks and then returns to the app in the middle of editing a tweet sheet, when he/she returns, the tweet sheet cancels.

I am using this code to present the tweet sheet (in case it helps):

```
- (void)sendTweet {
    TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler
    completionHandler =
    ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result)
        {
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Twitter Result: canceled");
                break;
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Twitter Result: sent");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Twitter Result: default");
                break;
        }
        [rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
    [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];

    // ...Set up the tweet sheet with text and image...

    [rootViewController presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];    
}
```

Is there any way to prevent the tweet sheet from canceling after the user switches apps? Any advice would be much appreciated!